# Easier way to find missing references in VS2010 C# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I just opened a solution from TFS using Visual Studio 2010. The solution contains more than 100 projects (if up to me, it would probably be less than 5) and many of them happen to miss a reference (to Unity dll's).

Is there any way to simplify the fixing of these references? Now I have to delete and re-add all of them manually. Hassle.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Using standalone VS, I don't think there's an easier way. You might be able to place the referenced dll(s) in a common location and write a simple script to process each .csproj (or .vbproj) file and alter the reference in the XML, but by the time you create such a script, you may have been able to complete the manual work.

Comment: You need to figure out the reason the reference is missing.

Comment: Well, Ramhound, they're "missing" because VS don't know where to locate them. That's why I would love to be able to update all these projects easily in one click.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the problem you need to find out from where it tries to load the files. You can do so looking in the project csproj file. You either have newer (or different) versions of the assemblys installed or you have a different file and folder structure. You need to recreate the file and folder structure that has been used in that project or rewrite the csproj file to the new location.

For the future you might want to change how 3rd party references are handled. I have good experiences using this approach: Define a ThirdPartyLibraries Folder where all those libraries go and check it in. It should be in the solution folder. Everybody has to put 3rd party libs in there from now on and use them instead.

Comment: This is exactly how we do it, but I think in this case (and this happens every time a solution is set up - almost), someone has forgot to update the reference - and this works for the person who set up the solution, but not for those who check it out, because the old reference that was used is not found in my tree. However, the question here is about simplifying the way to locate references for multiple projects in a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check out resharper,  it might do what you need for references.  I know it helps optimize and identify references in classes, not sure at the project level.  Resharper has a 30 day trial

Comment: I will try it and see if it can help me. So far no luck with it.

Comment: bemdahmon: i landed on this thread looking for then. So i assume this doesn't exist yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add all those binaries in to Binaries folder and add in to your TFS.

Now add the binaries as existing item in your solution items, so that when you open the solution it fetches all the solution items as well.

Make sure the references are added from the binaries folder.

Comment: I have all the binaries, it's just that the reference path was wrong when I got the projects from TFS.

Answer (score 0):

If the location of the referenced assembly has changed, then it is relative simple to do a Find and Replace in files on the .csproj files to replace the broken reference with the correct one.